# Laravel: Select from Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

in my Laravel App I have two tables:

```
Projects
- id
- user_id 
- name
- etc...

Images
- id
- project_id
- url
```

How can I achieve it, to show all the Projects each user has and all the connected images (each project can have up to 20 images (stored in FTP) and Link in Field URL - the project_id from table "Projects" will be saved in field images.project_id)?

I learned, that I can show the projects like this:

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')->where('user_id','=',$user->id)->get();
```

and I tried with

```
$images = DB::table('images')->where('project_id','=',$projects->id)->get();
```

But I get an error message:

```
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

What I am missing? Thank you for pointing me into the correct direction :-)

Kind Regards,

Stefan

Comment: You need to read up on [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) (thats why you are using Laravel in a first place!), after you are done with that read something on [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) or https://hackernoon.com/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209. Good luck! Also delete this questions since it adds no value even if answered (the answer would be long and I am not sure anyone here is going to waste time on it if its all in the documentation anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question i suggest to use [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) way like set up your models

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Image::class, 'project_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}

class Image extends Model
{
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Project::class, 'project_id');
    }
}
```

Now to find projects with their images you can query as

```
$projects = Project::with('images')->get();
```

Each object in `$projects` will have collection of their associated images.

To add filter for user you can use `whereHas` on relations

```
$projects = Project::with('images')
                    ->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user) {
                        $query->where('id', '=', $user->id);
                    })->get();
```

Comment: Dear Khalid, thank you very much! I was so close, but I set up the relationships wrong. Thank you for your effort and support! Kind Regards, Stefan